# Can only ping certain IP's over VPN

Tags: vpn, ping, networking, draytek

I have 2 Draytek Vigor 2830's set up with a IPSec VPN between the two which is working. Yet I can only ping the router in HQ (10.0.0.9) & the IPCortex (10.0.0.2), the outline below might help.

```
                    HQ                                     Remote Office
Local Network    10.0.0.0                                   10.0.10.0
Router           10.0.0.9 (Gateway for IPCortex)            10.0.10.1
                 10.0.0.1 (Gateway for rest of network)
```

IPCortex 10.0.0.2

In HQ the IPCortex SIP box uses 10.0.0.9 as its gateway the rest of the HQ network uses 10.0.0.1. The DHCP server runs on 10.0.0.1 for the HQ network, and in the site office 10.0.10.1 runs a DHCP as well.

From the site office, I can ping 10.0.0.9 & 10.0.0.2 fine. If I try and ping anything else it just doesn't go anywhere. 
Traceroute from Site Office PC shows 10.0.10.1 --> 10.0.0.9 --> Request timed out.
HQ Router (10.0.0.9) Ping diagnosis reaches IP's other than 10.0.0.2 but the Site Office Router (10.0.10.1) will only reach 10.0.0.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that all the other devices use a different gateway so their replies are being sent via 10.0.0.1 and therefore not reaching me? But what about HTTP, I have a printer on 10.0.0.3 which is normally accessible via HTTP but would the different gateway impact on accessing that via web-browser?

Comment: I have tried using traceroute and specifying the 10.0.0.9 as the Gateway to use but still no luck.

Comment: I have set a static route on a machine in the HQ and told it to use 10.0.0.9 for any ip's on the 10.0.10.0 network and I can ping the site office perfectly, but Site Office  --> HQ is still not working.

Comment: Can you set up the equivalent rule in the Site Office's router?